# Memory limit on imagecreatetruecolor()?

Tags: php

I need to create an image that is 23040 x 18688 pixels. When I make a short script I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92160 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\bvg\index.php on line 4

Why does it throw an error when 92160 bytes is well below the 1GB I allotted for it? Here is my code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor(23040,18688);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It tried to allocate 92160 *more* bytes than it had previously, which put it over the allowed memory size (so you were somewhere over 1073649664 bytes beforehand)

Comment: Because you have already used `1073741824` and are trying to allocate an extra `92160` which is putting it over the `memory_limit`

Comment: Note that you need a minimum of 23040 x 18688 x 4 bytes (1,722,286,080 bytes, or 1,681,920k or 1,682M) of memory just for the image, plus whatever memory is required by your script and any other variables that you use.... that's more than the 1024M maximum that you've configured

Comment: There are some User Contributed Notes on the `imagecreatetruecolor` PHP page that might help you out in setting the memory limit - [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php#99623) for example.

Comment: I've tried `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`
This will remove the memory limit in current script

Comment: While correct - this does remove the memory list - it doesn't answer the questions about what's needed to create a 23040x18688 image in PHP.

Comment: Never go for unlimited memory for one user request in production mode. Never.